# Compile Time: How can I check if a datatype (and or value) is being used within a method

Tags: c#, compilation, postsharp, il, visual-studio-2015

At compile time, how can I check if a data type (and or value) is being used within a method.

I'm attempting to build a living [architecture](https://github.com/bizmonger/Holoware) that supports plugins.

I want the compiler to throw an error if an event is not being raised within the plugin.

I'm using VS2015 Preview.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you tag the question with PostSharp? Are you using that?

Comment: PostSharp may have the ability to help during precompilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of validation is possible to implement using PostSharp. It is not trivial but easier than using Mono.Cecil. [SyntaxTreeVisitor](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_syntax_syntaxtreevisitor) and [ISyntaxReflectionService](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_reflection_syntax_isyntaxreflectionservice) is a good foundation for implementing the analysis algorithm which has to be invoked from [Aspect.CompileTimeValidate](http://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-validation#compiletimevalidate).

[Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) must be mentioned as well. It allows you to "extend" C# (or VisualBasic) compiler with custom diagnostics and it is very well integrated with VS2015.

Disclaimer: I'm PostSharp developer.

Comment: Disclaimer: I applied to be a postsharp evangelist. Thanks, I will research your links.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make the compiler throw that error for you. You might be able to introduce an extra build step that executes a C# console app that checks (using reflection) what you want.

Comment: Can reflection expose implementation details of a method?

Comment: Reflection can give you the bytes representing the il/opcodes; that sounds like implementation details. ;) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It would probably be easier to use Mono.Cecil to parse it.